# Using Registry class instead of Global variables. How to make it better

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to create a better registry class, so  I don't have to declare global variables like some database connections, using sensitive information in a global variable.

Here is an idea which I found online in some tutorial. I would like to ask if it is OK, or we can make it better in some other way?

```
class registry {
    private $register = array();

     public function __set($index, $value)  {
        $this->register[$index] = $value;
     }
     public function __get($index)  {
        return $this->register[$index];
     }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? for what kind of application are you building this registry class?

Comment: Actually for my website, for all Kinds of Global variables.
I don't want to use global varaibles, instead a registry class 
For example Database setting are normally globally avaiable. 

I don't want such thing. I am also new to PHP i normally Devlop in Java. So i am only a newbie in PHP

Comment: I understand it is for a website :) but why do you want a registry class instead of ie. a few singleton classes (like a Database class which can be reached using `$db = Database::instance();`)

Comment: @giorgio singletons are comfortable, but they are actually still global state, so it's just a global variable in disguise.

Comment: well not exactly... a class isn't a variable, a singleton class isn't 'global', in the sense that you have to explicitly call the class, it is not just hanging around there. If you are, example given, writing an authorization script, a singleton class is just exactly what you want, for security's sake. For database classes you do not want pollution (many db connections opened and not properly closed). Global variables are bad indeed, singleton classes are just fine, common and good practice!

Comment: btw you should read your own 'Globals are bad link' better, especially the 'alternatives' part, where the singleton pattern is explicitly stated as a good alternative ;)

Comment: Hi @giorgio, in the page it also says "Many uses of the Singleton Pattern are just thinly veiled globals". I don't want to say that Singleton are always bad, but since they provide global state they have many of the problems outlined in "Global variables are bad" (Non-locality, Implicit coupling, Concurrency issues, Testing and Confinement). [Singleton are Pathological Liars](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/) excellent article was an eye opener to me. (In Java, but same concepts apply)

Comment: well not exactly. In php on every page reload the 'application is totally rebuild', in java, after doing something, only the application state is altered. this is a HUGE difference, which means arguments for java do not automatically apply for php. In java as well as in php globals should be avoided, but in php singletons are allowed and in many times desirable, ie. in previous examples, as the 'global state' is only maintained for that particular request.

Comment: @giorgio, you've a point. However, even in this form they still hold the problems of tight coupling, hidden dependencies, and testing), but they get relieved of concurrency issues, only one of the problems I've listed. Said that, it is a controversial argument (see warnings on [singleton pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php) in the PHP manual) and people have different opinions. It's OK to have different opinions, we are on SO. Why don't you post your answer with your point of view?

Answer (score 4):

[Global variables are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). It doesn't matter if you've independent variables, an object holding them, or if you store them in an associative array, or if you use one or more Singleton Objects to hold them. All parts of your application will have a dependency on those magic values and will be difficult to test.

The alternative is called [dependency injection](http://www.potstuck.com/2009/01/08/php-dependency-injection/) allows you to feed those configuration values to the class that actually need them, without putting them in the global state.

There are also other advantages of dependency injection, like decoupling of dependencies. In other words, classes that depend on other classes don't have to create the dependency themselves, thus hard-wiring them, but a framework can inject them for you (set them in the object).

There are many frameworks supporting dependency injection, among them:

- [Symphony](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/)
- [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/)
- [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/)